# Why gulp users have a build folder for output

Tags: gulp

I am new to GULP and starting to organise where files should output. My main question is, 'why have a build folder for for outputting all compresseded etc files?'

This is an example folder structure I am seeing from many GULP tutorials

```
Project Folder
    js folder
    css folder
    vendor folder
    build folder
    index.html
```

What I am not understaning is why the GULP file dest is something like, 'build'? Surely the original files should be in a separate folder and output to the main css/js folders as that is what will be referenced in the index.html?

Many thanks for your help and opinions on this.

C

Comment: where will you put your prod deployment stuff??

Comment: I use Beanstalk and everything is versioned. I was thinking have a 'prod/dist' folder to output everything to where it normally is ie css/js folders in root?

Comment: so you can use prod/css and prod/js.. infact its the same structure that john-papa has in gulp-patterns

Comment: So do you mean in the HTML use <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prod/css/main.css">?

Comment: yes, exactly... have a look at gulp-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the structure is little different

> ```
> build/   
>  js/vendor.js   
>  js/source.js   
>  css/vendor.css   
>  css/source.css
> ```

please understand that ultimately, it's your choice and personal preference.

also the recommended folder structure for code is : folder per feature...
have a look at [gulp-pattern](https://github.com/johnpapa/gulp-patterns)